# Is ParallelPeriod causing issues with my MDX?

Tags: runtime-error, mdx

I have the following MDX query:

```
with

  MEMBER [Measures].[Prior Week] 
AS AGGREGATE(ParallelPeriod([Date].[Sun Weeks], 1, [Date].[Sun Weeks].CURRENTMEMBER), [Measures].[Value Count])

SELECT 
NON EMPTY 
{ 
   [Measures].[Value Count],
   [Measures].[Prior Week] 
} ON COLUMNS, 

NON EMPTY 
{ 
       ( [Date].[Sun Weeks].[Day].ALLMEMBERS ) 
} ON ROWS 
FROM [MyCube];
```

The sun weeks hierarchy is [Date].[Sun Weeks].[Sun Week Year].[Sun Week].[Day]

When I run the above query the [Prior Week] column produces `#Error`

Does anyone know why? How do I fix it? Does it have something to do do with ParallelPeriod?

Comment: if you double click on the cell with `#Error` in it then you should get the error message? (in SSMS or MDXStudio)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to explicitly force the first argument to be a set:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[Prior Week] AS 
   AGGREGATE(
      {ParallelPeriod(
        [Date].[Sun Weeks]
      , 1
      , [Date].[Sun Weeks].CURRENTMEMBER
      )}
   ,[Measures].[Value Count]
   )
```

But the first argument you've given ParallelPeriod is `[Date].[Sun Weeks]` ... is this a level in your cube? That function requires a level as its first argument.

If all you want to achieve is to go back 7 days then lag is easier:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[Prior Week] AS 
    (
      [Date].[Sun Weeks].CURRENTMEMBER.lag(7).item(0)
     ,[Measures].[Value Count]
    )
```

Or you could lag by 7 days and then jump up a level to the week:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[Prior Week] AS 
    (
      [Date].[Sun Weeks].CURRENTMEMBER.lag(7).parent
     ,[Measures].[Value Count]
    )
```